# Get only most recent value from ReplaySubject

Tags: rxjs6

Say I have a ReplaySubject:

```
const rs = new ReplaySubject();

rs.next(1);
rs.next(2);
rs.next(3);
```

if I do:

```
rs.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(v => {});
```

I will get the first value, but how do I get the most recent value, 3?

I tried

```
rs.pipe(takeLast(1))
rs.pipe(last())
```

but those didn't work.

Comment: This really depends on how you use your `ReplaySubject` instance. Does it ever complete? If not you can chain it with `shareReplay(1)` that will remember its last emission.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how to do this from the consumer-side, but from the producer-side, we can pass an integer to the constructor like so:

```
const rs = new ReplaySubject(1);  // pass 1 to the constructor

rs.next(1);
rs.next(2);
rs.next(3);

rs.subscribe(v => console.log('the value is:', v));
```

now you will get this output:

> the value is: 3

**If someone knows how to do this from the consumer-side, that would be great, please let me know.**

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely possible to use the `last()` operator. That is if you ever use `complete()` on the subject.

```
import { ReplaySubject, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { last } from 'rxjs/operators';    

const rs = new ReplaySubject();

rs.pipe(last()).subscribe(v => console.log(v));

timer(1000).subscribe(() => rs.next('a'));
timer(2000).subscribe(() => rs.next('b'));
timer(3000).subscribe(() => rs.next('c'));
timer(4000).subscribe(() => rs.complete());

// after 4s prints 'c'
```

Here you can see that after 4s the console will print the last emitted value, `c`.

**But**, if you simple subscribe to the `ReplaySubject`, it always prints the last passed value.

```
const rs2 = new ReplaySubject();

rs2.subscribe(v => console.log(v));

timer(1000).subscribe(() => rs2.next(1));
timer(2000).subscribe(() => rs2.next(2));
timer(3000).subscribe(() => rs2.next(3));

// after 1s prints 1
// after 2s prints 2
// after 3s prints 3
```

I have a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-53754631) for you, check out the console logs.